# Sync iPhone's contact with Facebook, Twitter, etc

Tags: ios, iphone, contacts

I am looking for an app capable of merging duplicated contacts and updating my iPhone contacts with Facebook and Twitter friends information. What's the best app out there for this?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looking at **[cobook](http://www.cobookapp.com/)**. It's pretty good at that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the answer you want, but:

- Merge duplicate contacts using Google Contacts. This is fairly simple to do by setting up a Gmail account and telling it to sync (and merge) contacts with your address book. Then you'll need to use the web interface to merge duplicates. It's possibly the least painful one I've seen.
- The built-in Twitter integration automatically syncs contacts where it can find matches, and the Facebook iPhone app was able to do the same (I don't use FB anymore so I can't test this now). In other words, two apps, not one, with the same outcome.

The merge option is more work than you're probably wanting to put in, but the amount of time it takes will be offset by the amount of time you're waiting for a perfect answer.

Comment: Disclosure: this is the technique I used years ago and I've never looked back.